# How many nVIDIA GPUs does my system actually have?

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, gpu, nvidia-geforce

This is silly, but in my situation I do not actually know the number of nVIDIA Grid K2 GPUs on my server (I can't physically go and verify).

The output of nvidia-smi is:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 367.64                 Driver Version: 367.64                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GRID K2             On   | 0000:86:00.0     Off |                  Off |
| N/A   41C    P8    29W / 117W |     10MiB /  4095MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GRID K2             On   | 0000:87:00.0     Off |                  Off |
| N/A   33C    P8    28W / 117W |      8MiB /  4095MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  GRID K2             On   | 0000:8B:00.0     Off |                  Off |
| N/A   34C    P8    28W / 117W |      8MiB /  4095MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

nvidia-smi -L gives:

```
GPU 0: GRID K2 (UUID: GPU-f38f91db-d219-6dae-3f2c-ccce0dee93b5)
GPU 1: GRID K2 (UUID: GPU-a165f882-655e-31c0-b6f0-46748129ff17)
GPU 2: GRID K2 (UUID: GPU-44daaa30-3e5b-558c-2775-1e9802be7e91)
```

The host machine is a 20-core, 2-socket Intel machine.

Now, I can't figure out why it shows 3 GPUs since 1 Grid K2 actually has 2 GPUs so nvidia-smi should actually show even number of Grid K2 GPUs (either 2 or 4 in my case).

Comment: Go and ask whoever provides that server what components have have been put into it?

Comment: The person who did the installation has left and is inaccessible.

Comment: Could you please add the output of `lspci | grep -i vga` to the question? Perhaps it’s somehow bus-related that one GPU isn’t showing up. /edit: Also, the output of `dmesg | egrep -i 'nvidia|nvrm'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like 3 by your stats, but you can make more detailed checks.

If your system is running Windows Server, then use from a cmd prompt:

```
wmic path win32_VideoController get AdapterRAM, Caption, DriverVersion
```

If you use Linux:

```
lspci | grep -i --color 'vga\|3d\|2d'
```

or

```
lshw -short | grep -i --color display
```

`nvclock` command should also show you clock info on GPUs.

These will list good info about the video adapters.

Comment: lspci | grep -i --color 'vga\|3d\|2d shows 4 of "VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104GL [GRID K2] (rev a1)"

Comment: Looks like you do have 4 GPUs and 2 are grouped-up in one adapter or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Try `nvidia-smi -L`

(From the man nvidia-smi output on a Linux system:)

-L, --list-gpus
List each of the NVIDIA GPUs in the system, along with their UUIDs.

**Edit:**
Re-reading the original question, I see that OP has already tried this solution and it is not what they are looking for.  Doh.